# How to work with a premise containing multiple ' if 's?

Tags: logic

> Premise 1:  If $A_1$ if $A_2$  ... if $A_a$, then $C_1$.
>   Premise 2: If $B_1$ if $B_2$  ... if $B_b$, then $C_2$.
>   $\ ----$
>   Conclusion: Then $C_3$ (whatever this is).

Please explain in simple English. I've only been exposed to premises with only one **if**.
As above, suppose a premise contains plural **if**s, which follow each other and are nested.
Then how do I make sense of the premise?   And the argument?

Footnote: I don't quote  [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/18366/8572) example from law, because I remain dazed.   I don't understand that answer, which has been upvoted 3 times but was denounced by 2 users in the comments.

Comment: I assume it just means If $A_1$ and $A_2$ and $A_3$ etc..

Comment: Re the linked legal example: No wonder you are confused by the answer - it misrepresents the meaning of the given statement, where the last if is not a condition to the conclusin, but rather part of an if-then-statement that need not be true, but only believed to be true by the actor ...

Comment: Note that one would write "If A then C$ as "Premis: A; Conclusion: C". Hence the many if's in your example do not parse well

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks. Sorry about that oversight. Better and right now?

Comment: -1 for "explain it like I'm 10 years old". If I had run into a strange 10 years old child on the street and they had asked me to explain to them several conditional premises arguments, I'd answer "Hey kid, where are your parents? Leave me alone, would you?", but additionally I despise the culture phenomenon that everything should be explainable to little children. Sorry, some things are just complicated in life, and even in math.

Comment: Simplest explanation is not synonymous with "explain it like I am a little child". I don't expect little children to have the mental acumen to handle abstract ideas like generic statements and inferences. I don't expect them to understand what a "well-formed formula" is or to follow inference rules. If you want to say that your ability to abstract and comprehend is that of a 10 years old child, let me remind you that there is a lower age limit of 13 for using this site, and perhaps it is best if you'd waited until you're at least equivalent to a 13 years old teenager. Or 18...

Comment: Not as worse, sure.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see:

> If it is raining I get wet if I do not have an umbrella with me if I leave the house.

is semantically the same as:

> If it is raining and I leave the house and I don't have an umbrella with me, then I get wet.

So you see that multiple nested if's can be combined to a single if about their conjucntion. C programmers will recognize that

```
if (rain) if (leave) if (!umbrella) getwet();
```

can be rewritten as

```
if (rain && leave && !umbrella) getwet();
```

for precisely this reason.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, I'm not a computer programmer. But does your example differ from that law example and my OP? Should you have ended with **I get wet** instead, as in: If it is raining   if I do not have an umbrella with me   if I leave the house,  **I get wet**?

Answer (score 0):

Your premises are not complete sentences. If we cut down to two sentences of premises, you get "if (A and B) then C".  In your more extended case you can add all the sentences in your premises into the conjunction.  Only if you have *all* the premises true are you guaranteed the truth of the conclusion (though the conclusion may be true even if some of the premises are false).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about that oversight. Better and right now? The premises ought now to be complete sentences.

Comment: More normally your premises would just be the sentences $A_1, A_2, \dots B_b$ and you would derive $C$.  You can have a premise that says "If A1 then C1$ or "If A1 and A2 then C2" and the above is how to read it.

Comment: To clarify, are you discussing just the normal premises with only 1 **if**? Instead, I'm asking about the different form: 'If A if B if C ... then D'.

Comment: This would be the same as if (A and B and C) then D